# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'execute', android studio 8.0 beta

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, asynchttpclient

I know many people have issues like mine, but the answers I found didn't seem to work.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;



import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by DJ on 6/29/2014.
 */
public class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... values){
        String result;
        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            HttpClient httpc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpp = new HttpPost("http://" + values[0] + "/AndroidConnection/Select.php");
            httpp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
            HttpResponse httpr = new httpc.execute(httpp);
            HttpEntity httpe = httpr.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpe.getContent();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch(Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
`
```

As you can see in this code, I used the HttpClient.execute command, but Android studio refers to .execute command as an error: `cannot resolve symbol 'execute'`.

I have already tried Invalidating Cache and restart. I also turned on Maven's auto import check box.

OS: win7 32-bit
JDK: jdk7(Java EE)
Android Studio: 8.0 beta

Comment: Could you post the full error output instead of `cannot resolve symbol...`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `new` in this line:

```
HttpResponse httpr = new httpc.execute(httpp);
```

You do not have to create a new object. You will only call the method `execute`